# Clear Cosmos console

Tags: c#, cosmos

I'm developing an Operating system with cosmos and I'm wondering if someone knew how to clear the console in Cosmos? I want to create a /clear command, and I've tried some solutions, but what is wrong with this code?
`Console.Clear();`

Comment: Youd expect that to work, but you could just send x numbers of blank lines and place the cursor at the top.

Comment: That may be working to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't scroll as there is no mouse because the GUI is a console. You can just do this(Sorry if there are errors, i've not used c# in 2 weeks.):

```
    if ((input == "clear"))
{
clear();
}

public static void clear()
{
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");


}
```

Comment: ye but you don't scroll in the os so it will work, adding lines will clear it as the lines are "", it will work but just a larger *.iso file

Comment: I just started with c#

Answer (score 0):

Console.clear();

This is the best way to clear the console.

Comment: The question already mentions your code, so I guess this is what didn't work for him..

Answer (score 0):

Just doing in short what Dragon Softwares posted
Use this Code

```
public static void clear()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
}
```

And call it using

```
clear();
```

Edit: The method

```
Console.Clear();
```

works in latest version of Cosmos OS tool now there is plug for that you can either update cosmos or use that plug in your cosmos template

Answer (score 0):

I Use Some Clear Method

```
Console.Clear()
```